# Has anyone successfully installed Nodejs Soap on Windows 7?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, node.js, soap, winapi

I've been trying for pretty much the whole day now to install [milewise's nodejs Soap client](https://github.com/milewise/node-soap).  I'm simply running the following from the cmd as an administrator:

```
cd: c:\Program Files\nodejs
npm install soap
```

It keeps getting stifled at the node-gyp rebuild file. I've received several different errors, but currently I am getting the following error:

```
error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Defaul.props" was not found.  
Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct and that the file exists on disk.
```

This is driving me crazy.  I'v tried several iterations of installing the [Windows 7 dependencies for node-gyp](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp).  Unfortunately, after successfully installing VS C++ 2010 express, MS Windows SDK + .NET Framework 4 will not install.

Has anyone out there had success installing this or any other Soap client for Nodejs on Windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

Installing [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Service Pack 1 Compiler Update for the Windows SDK 7.1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4422) (as suggested by https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp) fixed the `MSB4019` error for me.

The readme of that update states that the recommended order is

1. Visual Studio 2010
2. Windows SDK 7.1
3. Visual Studio 2010 SP1
4. Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Compiler Update for the Windows SDK 7.1